# sort numbers with if statement in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I try to build this code and create a bug that print and after the correct printing. I've got this code:

```
<?php
$A=3;
$B=10;
$C=5;

if ($A<=$B){
    if($C<=$A){
        echo $C,"</br>",$A,"</br>",$B;
    }
    if($B<=$C){
        echo $A,"</br>",$B,"</br>",$C;
    }
    else {
        echo $A,"</br>",$C,"</br>",$B;
    }
}
    if ($C<=$B){
        echo $C,"</br>",$B,"</br>",$A;

    if ($C<=$A){
        echo $B,"</br>",$C,"</br>",$A;
    }
    else{
        echo $B,"</br>",$A,"</br>",$C;
    }}



?>
```

And I take this as an answer:

```
3
5
105
10
3
```

instead of

```
3
5
10
```

that must to print
How could I correct that problem?

Answer (score 2):

try this code, you had forgotten the else:

```
$A=3;
$B=10;
$C=5;


if ($A<=$B){
    if($C<=$A){
        echo $C,"</br>",$A,"</br>",$B;
    }
    if($B<=$C){
        echo $A,"</br>",$B,"</br>",$C;
    }
    else {
        echo $A,"</br>",$C,"</br>",$B;
    }
}
else {
    if ($C<=$B){
        echo $C,"</br>",$B,"</br>",$A;
    }
    if ($C<=$A){
        echo $B,"</br>",$C,"</br>",$A;
    }
    else {
        echo $B,"</br>",$A,"</br>",$C;
    }
}
```